# Nested if statements problem in legacy .liquid

Tags: if-statement, liquid

I'm banging my head against the wall with this one since my syntax looks to be accurate but I'm not getting any results when trying to edit some legacy code on a Shopify storefront. For:

```
{% if product.metafields.custom_fields["custom_field_two"] != blank %}

      <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="share-pdp__details--tab" id="customtwoTab"
        onclick="displayDetails('customtwo')" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="customtwo">
        Section Main Title (This is displayed in all conditions) 
        {% if product.handle == 'product-one' %}- Product-specific added text {% else %}- Other product-specific added text {% endif %}
        <span class="tab-mobile__arrow"
          id="customtwo_arrow"><i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></span>
      </div>
```

I'm hoping to see the `- Other product-specific added text` but it's just not showing up once in my production dev environment. The `- Product-specific added text` is showing up, but nothing else.

Any ideas? Could something else be interfering?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. What is the actual value of `product.handle`? According to your mentioned behaviour I assume it to be `"product-one"`. If that's the case, why would you expect the output of the else case to be shown? With an `if ... else` you can only have either of the two outputs, depending on the result of your condition, but never both of them.

Comment: You can think of product.handle as a generic Liquid object. In this case it's pointing to 'product-one' which, in Liquid, is typically just the product URL pathname e.g. domain/products/product-one.

Comment: So again, if the condition `product.handle == 'product-one'` evaluates to true, why would you expect "Other product specifc added text" to appear? That's not how `if .. else ` works. And you should add a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ie, provide input data, and current and expected output ...